# create new branch for the same project on other platform

Tags: eclipse, git, android-studio

I'm new to branching staff, always worked only in master.

Now i have on my master - eclipse android project. I migrated it to Android Studio, then created on server a new branch from master-"new_branch".

And i need is to store this migrated version to a "new_branch", so eclipse project would remain on "master". How can i do it?

What i think is that i need to clone the sources and delete all files and replace them with android studio project, then push to "new_branch", but i'm not sure, i don't want to accidently delete the master eclipse project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new branch and checkout to it,

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

after that delete all files you need and add new Androin Studio files. After that you ned to commit it to your new branch and push to remote repository.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add new files"
git push origin new_branch
```

So in finish you have 2 branches

1) Eclipse files (master)

2) Android Studio files (new_branch)

Comment: so i need to clone the project with two branches, then git checkout -b new_branch, and then everything you described?